# Android Textview doesn't show text in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a Fragment to my FrameLayout, it seems that it is added correctly, but then i can't see the text of the TextView.

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="#34f5d6"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The FragmentClass:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.CharacterPickerDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimerClass extends Fragment {
        public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
            TimerClass fragment = new TimerClass();
            return fragment;
        }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
        ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container,false);

        return root;
    }
}
```

And the code i use to add the fragment to the FrameLayout

```
    FragmentTransaction tx= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment= TimerClass.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
    tx.replace(R.id.fl, fragment);
    tx.commit();
```

I don't undestand why it doesn't show the text, I tryed to change the color of the text but it doesn't work. 
If I change the background of the TextView, it works; also if I add an OnClockListener on the TextView, it works. Only it doesn't show the text.

Can you help me?

---

EDIT:
I found the solution: the problem was with the FrameLayout; it's top part was covered by the action bar. 
By fixing the layout of the FrameLayout the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

First simply change this

```
    ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container,false);
    return root;
```

to

```
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container,false);
    return root;
```

Also this one

```
 public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        TimerClass fragment = new TimerClass();
        return fragment;
    }
```

to

```
public static TimerClass getInstance() {
    TimerClass fragment = new TimerClass();
    return fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is only with height and width of your **TextView** because you have sated them as match_parent

so try to replace

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="#34f5d6"/>
```

with

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="#34f5d6"/>
```